# GWT 2, Spring 3 good working example / demo of client - server communication

Tags: java, spring, gwt, maven, rpc

I wouldn't normally post a question just asking where to find a good demo of something like this but I have spent a considerable amount of time over the last few days trying out a number of demo's I can find that are supposed to be for integrating GWT 2 and Spring 3 but, so far, every one of them has had some issue where I cannot get it to run locally so that I can learn from it.

I simply would like a demo app that has communication from the GWT client side to the Spring server-side using RPC preferably with Maven as well. I already have some experience with GWT and have made my own small apps that make use of RPC calls to the server but it is not integrated with Spring. Likewise, I have experience with Spring as well but getting them to work together is proving to be a pain.

I have seen some tutorials about Roo but every one so far has not worked for me once I build it with Roo. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: I am having the same problems. i think i have gone through 10 or more tutorials and demos on this subject. NON OF THEM WORK!. its just amazing how they all fail to deliver something that should be relatively simple. I hope i'll get to something that works eventually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using spring and gwt together. I have choosed [spring4gwt](http://code.google.com/p/spring4gwt/), it is quite satisfactory..

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Spring Roo, amazing project.
http://www.springsource.org/roo

Answer (score 0):

Check this article about how to integrate Spring and GWT : http://crazygui.wordpress.com/2011/09/23/spring-gwt-integration-using-the-requestfactory-api/